# Event handlers on User Information List

Tags: event-handlers, alert, user-profile

Has anyone ever tried adding an event handler to the User Information List of a site collection? Or for that matter, an alert?

I'd try it out, but was just wondering if there were any issues I should be aware of.

Comment: What are you trying to do with it if I might ask?

Comment: It was a hypothetical question that I was asked recently, so I have no firm requirements. We have a collaboration environment (WSS only) and some site collections contain sensitive information. The site collection admins were asking if there was a way to be notified when people were given access to the site collection (intentionally or not) by the site owners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to add event handlers to the user info list.

Please see this following thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/81aae5ef-9621-48c5-ad52-706e5d6a0f05

That was me asking the question.